# Open two terminal windows side by side

Tags: terminal

If I am in Bash and type

```
vim -O file1 file2
```

I will get two files opened side by side.
How can I get a similar effect but for `:terminal` windows, not for files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify commands to be run using the `-c` argument.  Therefore, this should work for you:

```
vim -c 'terminal ++curwin' -c 'vertical terminal'
```

If your goal is just to have two terminal windows side-by-side, there are also non-vim solutions to this which may be more appropriate depending on your use case e.g. GNU screen, tmux.

Comment: Also, if you are going to type this by hand, you can shorten it to `vim +'ter++curwin' +'vert ter'`.